# Cable modem ping times go to thousands of milliseconds after 10 minutes of use

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, cable-modem, internet-speed

I have a wireless router (NetGear WNDR4500) which has a wired connection to a cable modem (Thompson DCM275).

My connection to the wireless router seems to be working fine and the traceroute and ping times are quite fast. But the connection from the wireless router to the cable modem doesn't seem to be working properly sometimes. When I turn the modem off and then on again the traceroute and ping times are fine. But sometimes after say 10 minutes or more the traceroute and ping times to the cable modem increase to thousands of milliseconds. When I turn the modem off and on again the issue goes away again.

Any ideas about what can be the issue?

Answer (score -1):

It means the packets, coming to your router from provider are accumulated, this hapens due to low signal level of your ISP. either you can replace your wireless router in the top most position of your roof, or you should ask your Internet provider to change the frequencylevel ...

Comment: I don't understand the relevance of the location of my wireless router.