# How to check if there is a congestion in my network?

Tags: networking, connection

How can I check if there is congestion between my wireless router and my cable modem?

[Cable modem ping times go to thousands of milliseconds after 10 minutes of use](https://superuser.com/questions/622359/an-issue-with-network-connection)

Comment: Should be added to the existing question; [An issue with network connection](http://superuser.com/questions/622359/an-issue-with-network-connection)

Comment: The questions are related but this is not an exact duplicate of the other one. An answer to one of them doesn't need to be an answer to the other one.